# Swift framework nested classes are not exported well in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, nested

I have the following classes contained by Geography.framework (a Swift framework project):

```
public class Contact : NSObject
{
    public static let  Table: String = "contacts"

    public class Fields : NSObject
    {
        public static let  Id: String = "_id"
        public static let  Name: String = "name"
        static let  rawId: String = "rawId"
    }
}


public class Country : NSObject
{
    public class Fields : NSObject
    {
        public static let  Id: String  = "_id"
        public static let  Prefix: String = "prefix"
        static let  rawId: String  = "rawId"
    }
}
```

In my swift app using this framework everything works smoothly:

```
import geography

func setFields()
{
    var contactName:String = Contact.Fields.Name
    var countryPrefix:String = Country.Fields.Prefix
    var contactsTable: String  = Country.Table
}
```

Well, if I use the same Geography.framework in ObjectiveC, I see Contact and Country class but the nested classes Fields are not seen. Also the value of Contact.Table is not seen.

What I need to do in order to have same library structure and library usage in ObjectiveC?

Thank you,

Comment: I guess you can't since objective-C does not support nested classes. You are probably going to need to write a wrapper in swift that exposes these things in a objective-C friendly interface.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have some example on how to do this ?

Answer (score 11):

You have to be explicit here with definition for ObjC.

```
public class Country: NSObject {

    @objc(CountryFields) public class Fields: NSObject {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This should expose your Switf's `Country.Fields` for your ObjC as `CountryFields`. I haven't tested it but I believe you don't have to be explicit about inheriting from `NSObject`. `@objc` attribute should do it for you when compiling.

Update for Swift 3:

Looks like this was broken in Swift 3 and won't be fixed. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2267?focusedCommentId=21033&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-21033

Comment: Works in Swift 4.2

Answer (score 3):

You can use a trick with `typealias` to have the same syntax when using it :

```
public class Contact : NSObject
{
    public static let  Table: String = "contacts"

    typealias Fields = ContactFields
}

@objcMembers
public class ContactFields : NSObject
{
    public static let  Id: String = "_id"
    public static let  Name: String = "name"
    static let  rawId: String = "rawId"
}

public class Country : NSObject
{
    typealias Fields = CountryFields
}

@objcMembers
public class CountryFields : NSObject
{
    public static let  Id: String  = "_id"
    public static let  Prefix: String = "prefix"
    static let  rawId: String  = "rawId"
}
```

Comment: For those reading, this means you can continue to use the swifty namespaced syntax of Contact.Fields in your .swift code, while use the more obj-c-like naming of ContactFields in your objc code, as obj-c doesn't support nested swift classes.