# Use Swift nested class as UIViewController in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, storyboard

Do you guys know if it's possible to use a Swift nested class as UIViewController in Storyboard?

I'm looking into different ways to structure my projects, one of which is grouping related classes by nesting them in the same main class.

Let me explain with an example:

Say I have a screen for displaying my app's settings which needs a UIViewController and a model.
I could create 2 classes: `SettingsController` and `SettingsModel`, but I'm wondering if it wouldn't be nice to have it structured otherwise by having a main class `Settings` containing nested classes `Controller` and `Model` like so

```
class Settings {
   class Controller: UIViewController {
      ...
   }
   class Model {
      ...
   }
}
```

That way I could use them by doing `Settings.Controller` and `Settings.Model` which I think would look pretty nice.

Now this works fine expect when using storyboard. In Storyboard when I select a view controller to set the custom class, if I type in `Setting.Controller` and hit enter, the field does not validate and is cleared.

So my question is do you guys know what I'm doing wrong or if this is simply not possible?

Comment: The whole problem is the fact the Cocoa/CocoaTouch are written in Objective-C, therefore Swift features like generics, nested classes, enums etc. are not supported. That's one of the reasons SwiftUI is such a big thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, it's after having posted the question that I found a solution so I'm sharing it for posterity.

So there was 1 problem to the way I was trying to do it:

1. Nested classes are references by using the dot
   notation: `Settings.Controller` but Interface Builder does not
   see that as a valid class name

The solution was simple, give the controller it's own Objc name:

```
class Settings {
   @objc(SettingsController)
   class Controller: UIViewController {
   }
   ...
}
```

By doing this you give the nested controller an ObjC name thereby exposing it the Interface Builder. Now you can reference the controller by filling in `SettingsController`.

Comment: I tried this before (I thought it would work as well), and it didn't work on my mac somehow. Glad it did on yours!

Comment: This works excellent on views for me, but not for controllers. Well it works when building, but the Storyboard cannot find the class so I can't connect any outlets. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think storyboards supports that (yet), so in the meantime you need to use some workarounds.

If all you want is the syntax `Settings.Controller`, you can do this: (Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47500802/5133585))

Declare your `Settings.Controller` class not as a nested class, but as a standalone class `SettingsController`:

```
class SettingsController : UIViewController { ... }
```

Then in `Settings`, add a `typealias`:

```
class Settings {
    typelias Controller = SettingsController
    class Model { ... }
}
```

Now you can use `SettingsController` in the storyboard, but `Settings.Controller` in code.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper! Because of your mentioning typealias I did some extra research and found a way to give an ObjC name to my class thereby fixing the problem! I posted my solution below!